# PDW File Browser for TinyMCE - Upload Path

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, file-upload, tinymce

I integrated PDW File Browser (TinyMCE plugin) to TinyMCE editor. But when I clicked "Insert/Edit Image button >>> General tab >>> Browse button (next to the Image URL field)", I got this error message:

```
"Upload folder doesn't exist or $uploadpath in config.php is set wrong!"
```

I'm sure I have set everything up correctly. I have set the "upload path":

```
$uploadpath = "/en/images/";
```

And tried use one of below "define()" methods (in "config.php", line 122 - 126), as the plugin creator suggested:

```
//define('DOCUMENTROOT', '/home/httpd/httpdocs');

//define('DOCUMENTROOT', 'c:\\webroot\\example.com\\www');

//define('DOCUMENTROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

//define('DOCUMENTROOT', realpath((@$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] && file_exists(@$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) ? $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] : str_replace(dirname(@$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', realpath('.')))));

define('DOCUMENTROOT', realpath((getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') && preg_match('#^'.preg_quote(realpath(getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT'))).'#', realpath(__FILE__))) ? getenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT') : str_replace(dirname(@$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', str_replace(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, '/', dirname(__FILE__)))));
```

None of them work. Did anybody experience the same problem? How to fix it?

Comment: what happens if you set $uploadpath = "";  ?

Answer (score 1):

DOCUMENTROOT defined here will point only to www or htdocs directory. So if you have sub-folder in which(which happens when testing locally) your website files are hosted; add that too to the $uploadpath.

Change your code to

```
$uploadPath = "/mywebsite/en/images/";
```

where mywebsite represents your website directory.